# Test Class for custom metadata

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests, test-setup

Getting the error of List has no row assignment in test class. How should i query the custom metadata in test class
Apex -

```
public with sharing class GetAccountsController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static DataTableResponse GetAllAccounts(String TableName, String countryCode,String stateCode)
    {
        List<DataTableColumns> lstDataColumns = new List<DataTableColumns>();
        List<SObject> lstDataTableData = new List<SObject>();
        List<string> columnList = new List<string>();
        List<string> fieldAPINameList = new List<string>();
        
        Get_Accounts__mdt accMetadata = [SELECT Id, DeveloperName, Field_Value__c, Header_Value__c, Query__c, Table_Title__c FROM Get_Accounts__mdt WHERE DeveloperName =: TableName];
        
        if(accMetadata != null)
        {
            if(accMetadata.Header_Value__c != null)
            {
                columnList = accMetadata.Header_Value__c.split(',');
            }
            
            if(accMetadata.Field_Value__c != null)
            {
                fieldAPINameList = accMetadata.Field_Value__c.split(',');
            }
        }
        
        for(integer i = 0; i < columnList.size(); i++)
        {
            
            DataTableColumns datacolumns = new DataTableColumns( columnList[i].trim() , 
                                                                fieldAPINameList[i].substringBefore(':').trim(), 
                                                                fieldAPINameList[i].substringAfter(':').trim());
            
            lstDataColumns.add(datacolumns);
        }
        
        String finalQuery = accMetadata.Query__c;
        if(countryCode!=null && stateCode!=null){
            string whereClause='';
            whereClause += ' BillingCountryCode= \'' + countryCode + '\' ';
            whereClause += ' AND BillingStateCode= \'' + stateCode + '\' ';
            finalQuery += ' WHERE' + whereClause;
        }
        
        for(SObject SObjectItem : Database.query(finalQuery))
        {
            lstDataTableData.add(SObjectItem);
        }
        
        DataTableResponse finalWrapper = new DataTableResponse();
        finalWrapper.lstDataTableColumns = lstDataColumns;
        finalWrapper.lstDataTableData = lstDataTableData;
        return finalWrapper;
    }
    
    public class DataTableColumns {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String label {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled       
        public String fieldName {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String type {get;set;}
        
        public DataTableColumns(String label, String fieldName, String type)
        {
            this.label = label;
            this.fieldName = fieldName;
            this.type = type;          
        }
    }
    
    public class DataTableResponse {
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<DataTableColumns> lstDataTableColumns {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<sObject> lstDataTableData {get;set;}      
    }
}
```

Test class

```
@isTest
public class GetAccountsControllerTest {
    static testMethod void testAccount(){
         Get_Accounts__mdt objSample = new Get_Accounts__mdt();
        
        Test.startTest();
        GetAccountsController.GetAllAccounts('objSample', 'IN', 'KA');
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Custom metadata
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get_Accounts__mdt accMetadata = [
  SELECT Id, DeveloperName, Field_Value__c, Header_Value__c, Query__c, Table_Title__c 
  FROM Get_Accounts__mdt 
  WHERE DeveloperName =: TableName];
```

This specific version of SOQL inline query will throw a QueryException if anything other than *exactly* one record is returned.

The "List has no rows for assignment" error occurs when the query returns 0 rows when using this method. You should change your query to use a list, then check if the list is empty:

```
Get_Accounts__mdt[] accMetadata = [
  SELECT Id, DeveloperName, Field_Value__c, Header_Value__c, Query__c, Table_Title__c 
  FROM Get_Accounts__mdt 
  WHERE DeveloperName =: TableName];
if(!accMetadata.isEmpty()) { // replaces if(accMetadata != null)
  Get_Accounts__mdt metadataValue = accMetadata[0];
  if(metadataValue.Header_Value__c != null) {
    columnList = metadataValue.Header_Value__c.split(',');
  }
  if(metadataValue.Field_Value__c != null) {
    fieldAPINameList = metadataValue.Field_Value__c.split(',');
  }
}
```

In addition, your unit test doesn't actually create a CMDT record in the database; you need to use an existing record that you know exists. You do not need to use `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)`, because metadata and most Setup objects are accessible in isolation.

Comment: If I replace it from null to isEmpty, it throws an error Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void isEmpty() from the type Get_Accounts__mdt. Also want to know is my test class is correct, or do i need to do any changes?

Comment: @user111906 you need to use a list of `Get_Accounts__mdt` (in my answer, written as `Get_Accounts__mdt[]`). I realized I left out some changes, but the code still should have compiled. Your unit test is not necessarily correct, either. It must depend on an existing CMDT in the database, rather than trying to create one at runtime.